# How to make a donut chart in tkinter using matplotlib Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, donut-chart

I am trying to build a simple program using tkinter and python 3.6. I am stuck when I try to plot a donut chart in my tkinter window using the matplotlib Figure and canvas.

I know how to make a donut chart using the matplotlib pyplot, using a very simple code I found on: https://python-graph-gallery.com/160-basic-donut-plot/

```
# library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create data
size_of_groups=[12,11,3,30]

# Create a pieplot
plt.pie(size_of_groups)
#plt.show()

# add a circle at the center
my_circle=plt.Circle( (0,0), 0.7, color='white')
p=plt.gcf()
p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)

plt.show()
```

I have read that the plots in tkinter should be made using the matplotlib.figure:
[Placing plot on Tkinter main window in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440167/placing-plot-on-tkinter-main-window-in-python)
Can someone help me how to adjust the code above to be able to plot it inside a Figure that I can place in tkinter canvas?

So far I have only been able to make the pie plot

```
fig = plt.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,5))
a = fig.add_subplot(111)
a.pie([20,30,50]) #an example data
a.legend(["20","30","50")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
window= tk.Tk()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()
window.mainloop()
```

But I am unable to add a circle in the center that would hide that part of the pie. Any ideas on how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a good idea not to use  `pyplot` at all when creating a tk GUI. This is entirely possible using the respective matplotlib objects directly.

```
import matplotlib.figure
import matplotlib.patches
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pie([20,30,50]) 
ax.legend(["20","30","50"])

circle=matplotlib.patches.Circle( (0,0), 0.7, color='white')
ax.add_artist(circle)

window= tk.Tk()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, ax.add_artist(circle) was exactly what I was missing to complete the plot